# MacOS Reset Window Position of all Apps

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, script

I want to reset **all** Window Positions of my Apps and Programms. It would take so long to reset the .plist file of any App. Is there any Script or Software to reset them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many, if not all apps, save their state at quit into a specific folder, per user…

`~/Library/Saved Application State/`

You can delete the contents of that - but be careful, some of those are aliases.
Don't throw out the aliases, just throw out the contents, then they can rebuild properly.
Any that are just a folder & not an alias, you can choose to delete either the contents or the entire folder. They will re-create at next launch/quit cycle.

BTW, this won't just reset window positions, it will also reset such as which files were open, etc. I'm not certain of the entire list of what's saved, but it's not in any way 'dangerous' to delete the saved states, if you don't need specific files to auto-open at next launch.